# Is it wrong to use global variables or dictionaries to pass variables to threads if I just need to read from them?

Tags: python, multithreading

The following code reads data from different instruments. Two threads read from two separate instruments and the main thread just adds 1 to variable a and prints all values. I use dictionaries to be able to print the data that is read in the threads. I have recently read that this is bad practice and that it's better to use a Queue. Is it still wrong to use a dictionary or a global variable if all I'm doing is just reading the values from the variables in the threads? I'm not trying to change them. I just need to read them. If it is wrong, is my best option to use a Queue?

```
import serial
import struct
import threading
import readkrohne
import keyboard
import time

Krohnehigh = readkrohne.comport('COM4')
Krohnelow = readkrohne.comport('COM6')

CONST_SER_PORT = 'COM11'
serDataq = serial.Serial(
    port = CONST_SER_PORT,
    timeout= 0.5
    )

serDataq.reset_input_buffer()

numofchannel=2 #if you modify the slist, you need modify this accordingly
numofbyteperscan=2*numofchannel
def scan(output):
    serDataq.write(b"start\r")       #start scanning
    while True:
        try:
            i= serDataq.in_waiting
            if (i//numofbyteperscan)>0:
                response = serDataq.read(i - i%numofbyteperscan)
                count=(i - i%numofbyteperscan)//2
                response2=bytearray(response)
                Channel=struct.unpack("<"+"h"*count, response2)
                output['Voltage'] = (round((Channel[0]/32768*10), 3))
                output['Current'] = (round((Channel[1]/32768*10)*(1000/498.4), 3)) #divided by 498.4 ohms and multiplied by 1000 to get milliamps
        except:
            pass

def kscan(krohne):
    while True:
        krohne['High'] = Krohnehigh.FlowRate()
        krohne['Low'] = Krohnelow.FlowRate()
        time.sleep(0.03)

#Dictionaries
output = {'Voltage': 0, 'Current': 0}
krohne = {'High': 0, 'Low': 0}
a = 0

#Creating and starting the threads that will run scan and kscan functions
t1 = threading.Thread(target=scan, args=(output,))
t1.daemon = True
t1.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=kscan, args=(krohne,))
t2.daemon = True
t2.start()

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):    #if key 'x' is pressed, stop the scanning and terminate the program
        serDataq.write(b"stop\r")
        time.sleep(1)           
        serDataq.close()
        print('Good-Bye')
        break

    a +=1
    print (f'{krohne["High"]:.3f} {krohne["Low"]:.3f} {a:.3f} {output["Voltage"]:.3f} {output["Current"]:.3f}', end='\r')
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: its not bad its fine ... its bad if there is the possibility of writing two things simultaneously ... reading should be no problem if its only being updated in a single thread

Comment: The key phrase here is `immutable data` -- as long as the data structure is guaranteed never to change while threads are reading from it, then no serialization is necessary.  You do want to be very careful that nobody ever changes the data structure, though -- best practice would be to "hide" the data structure in a file where only a few privileged functions can access it, and force other code to call those functions rather than allowing them to access the data structure directly.  That way you only have to verify a small amount of code for correctness, rather than every file in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Which is the better tool, a hammer? or a saw? Maybe the answer depends on whether you want to cut a board, or drive a nail.

I don't know a name for what you've done, but it has its advantages, and it has its disadvantages.

- Advantage: The threads run completely independently of each other. It doesn't matter whether the main thread is faster or slower than either of the other two threads.
- Disadvantage: The lack of synchronization means that the main thread may sometimes miss readings from either instrument (if it runs slower), or it may sometimes log duplicate readings (if it runs faster.)

If you choose to use a queue (or two queues) instead, then

- Advantage: Every reading will be logged, and it will be logged only one time.
- Disadvantage: If the main thread is unable to keep up with the other two threads, then the queue will become full, and the other threads may be delayed in obtaining subsequent readings.

Which is better? That depends on why your program reads those instruments, and on who consumes the logged data. Only you can decide.